# using tfrecord but getting file too large

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create a tfrecord from a folder of numpy arrays, the folder contains about 2000 numpy files of 50mb each.

```
def convert(image_paths,out_path):
    # Args:
    # image_paths   List of file-paths for the images.
    # labels        Class-labels for the images.
    # out_path      File-path for the TFRecords output file.    
    print("Converting: " + out_path)
    # Number of images. Used when printing the progress.
    num_images = len(image_paths)    
    # Open a TFRecordWriter for the output-file.
    with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(out_path) as writer:        
        # Iterate over all the image-paths and class-labels.
        for i, (path) in enumerate(image_paths):
            # Print the percentage-progress.
            print_progress(count=i, total=num_images-1)
            # Load the image-file using matplotlib's imread function.
            img = np.load(path)
            # Convert the image to raw bytes.
            img_bytes = img.tostring()
            # Create a dict with the data we want to save in the
            # TFRecords file. You can add more relevant data here.
            data = \
                {
                    'image': wrap_bytes(img_bytes)
                }
            # Wrap the data as TensorFlow Features.
            feature = tf.train.Features(feature=data)
            # Wrap again as a TensorFlow Example.
            example = tf.train.Example(features=feature)
            # Serialize the data.
            serialized = example.SerializeToString()        
            # Write the serialized data to the TFRecords file.
            writer.write(serialized)
```

i think it converts about 200 files and then i get this

```
Converting: tf.recordtrain
- Progress: 3.6%Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_record.py", line 71, in <module>
out_path=path_tfrecords_train)
  File "tf_record.py", line 54, in convert
writer.write(serialized)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_record.py", line 236, in write
self._writer.WriteRecord(record, status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: tf.recordtrain; File too large
```

Any suggestions to fix this would be helpful, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the limits are to tfrecords but the more common approach assuming you have enough disk space is to store your dataset over several tfrecords file e.g. store every 20 numpy files in a different tfrecords file.

Comment: Oh okay , I thought it was standard to fill the datasets in a single tfrecord, thanks I’ll look into this